# SSRS - Format Percentage with 1 decimal on concatenated value

Tags: ssrs-2012

How can I format a value in percentage with 1 decimal place on a pie chart label with concatenated valued. The value comes from my SQL query which is float then I use FORMATPERCENT in SSRS Expression.

```
=Fields!Category.Value & " - " & "(" & FormatPercent(Fields!CallCountPercent.Value) & ")"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
=Fields!Category.Value & " - " & "(" & Format(Fields!CallCountPercent.Value,"P1") & ")"
```

Answer (score 0):

Select Chart Series Labels Property

**Click Label:#PERCENT{P0}** For 0 decimal point
**Click Label:#PERCENT{P1}** For 1 decimal point
**Click Label:#PERCENT** For 2 decimal point(by default)